# How to configure Wildfly load balancing with redirect

Tags: load-balancing, keycloak, jboss-eap-7, wildfly-12

I am working with wildfly undertow load balancer , and I added following configuration in standalone-load-balancer.xml but my request is not getting redirected?
I added reverse proxy handler and host to the Undertow subsystem  as :

```
<handlers>
       <reverse-proxy name="keycloak-handler">
       <host name="keycloak-host" outbound-socket-binding="remote-host" path="/auth"/>
      </reverse-proxy>
 </handlers>
```

And then I defined outbound socket bindings for remote hosts as :

```
 <outbound-socket-binding name="remote-host">
            <remote-destination host="192.168.1.5" port="8443"/>
 </outbound-socket-binding>
```

And then added the reverse proxy to a location as :

```
<host name="default-host">
    <location name="/auth" handler="keycloak-handler"/>
     <filter-ref name="load-balancer"/>
</host>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake I was doing here is , my load balancer was with ssl enabled and I was communicating with keycloak via 8443 which expecting load balancer and keycloak both with same certificates. So to get rid off this , I have connected to keycloak via 8080 port and I have enabled ssl only with load balancer . So after changing below code it worked for me:

```
<outbound-socket-binding name="remote-host">
            <remote-destination host="192.168.1.5" port="8080"/>
 </outbound-socket-binding>
```